# Does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors

I'm not sure what is occurring here. The model was auto generated from the database and I can't see anything obvious (mind you it is 2.30am UK time at the moment so maybe I'm half asleep). I am getting the error: ActiveCitizenSystemMimic.Models.ActiveCitizenProperties does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments.

Model:

```
namespace ActiveCitizenSystemMimic.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ActiveCitizenProperties
    {
        public int FK_ActiveCitizen { get; set; }
        public int FK_PropertyType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
List<ActiveCitizenProperties> activeCitizenProperties = new List<ActiveCitizenProperties>();
activeCitizenProperties.Add(new ActiveCitizenProperties(1, 2));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may replace your code to:

```
List<ActiveCitizenProperties> activeCitizenProperties = new List<ActiveCitizenProperties>();
activeCitizenProperties.Add(new ActiveCitizenProperties(){ FK_ActiveCitizen = 1, FK_PropertyType = 2 });
```

Your "auto-generated" class obviously doesn't contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments. If it has, it would be like this:

```
namespace ActiveCitizenSystemMimic.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ActiveCitizenProperties
    {
        public int FK_ActiveCitizen { get; set; }
        public int FK_PropertyType { get; set; }

        public ActiveCitizenProperties(int a, int b)
        {
            this.FK_ActiveCitizen = a;
            this.FK_PropertyType = b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks also for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The errors means what it does say: ActiveCitizenProperties constructor doesn't accept two parameters. In the code given no constructor defined in the class at all.

You may use though:

```
new ActiveCitizenProperties { FK_ActiveCitizen = 1, FK_PropertyType = 2 };
```

Comment: Thanks abatishchev. I just also needed to ensure I had the parenthesis as per Alvin Wong's answer.

Comment: @user975516: Do you mean `new ActiveCitizenProperties() { }` instead of just `new ActiveCitizenProperties { }`? They aren't required, and Resharper for instance hints to omit them.