# Code-First SQL Server ASP.NET MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am a VB.NET programmer, but I am trying to learn C# and MVC in my spare time. I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.1.0.0 and I am trying to do code-First database creation in a local instance of SQL Server.

I was able to get the first database table to update in the database when I ran `Update-Database` from within the IDE, but when I added a second table that has a PK/FK relationship with the first, I am getting a red line under `[ForeignKey]` which reads

> Does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

I have been searching all over and not getting anywhere. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. By the way, the first table is a PK/FK relationship to the `AspNetUsers` table.

```css
public class BuildDatabase : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Companies Companies { get; set; }
    public virtual NotaryProfile NotaryProfile { get; set; }
}

public class Companies
{
    [Key]
    [Column("CompanyID")] // Did this as the database will reflect TableName_ColumnName instead.
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsNotary { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NotaryProfile> NotaryProfile { get; set; }
}

public class NotaryProfile
{
    [Key]
    public int NotaryID { get; set; }
    public string NamePrefix { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string NameSuffix { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int DefaultState { get; set; }
    public int DefaultCounty { get; set; }
    public bool IsSigningAgent { get; set; }
    public bool HasABond { get; set; }
    public decimal BondAmount { get; set; }
    public bool HasEandO { get; set; }
    public decimal EandOAmount { get; set; }
    public bool ElectronicNotarizationsAllowed { get; set; }
    public string ElectronicTechnologyUsed { get; set; }
    public string ComissionNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommissionIssued { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommssionOriginal { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommissionExpires { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommissionFiledOn { get; set; }
    public string SOSAuditNumber { get; set; }
    public string CommissionDesc { get; set; }
    [Foreignkey("CompanyID")] // Companies.CompanyID = PK
    public int CompanyID { get; set; } // PK/FK relationship.
    public Companies Companies { get; set; } // Reference to Companies table above.
}

public class SchemaDBContext : IdentityDbContext<BuildDatabase>
{
    public SchemaDBContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection"){}

    public DbSet<Companies> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NotaryProfile> NotaryProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# “does not contain a constructor that takes '1' arguments”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620852/c-sharp-does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-1-arguments)

Comment: C# is case sensitive (unlike VB.NET).  The foreign key attribute should be ForeignKey, not Foreignkey.  Not positive this is your issue but it may be.

Comment: I'd highly recommend purchasing [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) it's going to be a huge help and one of the best investments you can make

Comment: @nickles80 Thanks for telling me about that. I was not aware that everything in C# is case sentisive. At least in VB.NET, the IDE will auto-case, but it doesn't seem to be that way in C#. Good to know. I don't get the error now. I have not executed the code yet to see if this works or not. Will do shortly.

Answer (score 0):

One of your classes (probably `NotaryProfile`) needs to reference another object (the foreign key relationship) but there is no constructor in that class that accepts an argument to establish that relationship, e.g.:

```
public NotaryProfile(int companyId) {
  this.companyId = companyId;
}
```

BTW, a better way to establish that relationship is to use the actual class type rather than the ID, as in:

```
public class NotaryProfile {
  ...
  public Company Company { get; set; }
  // Instead of this:
  // public int CompanyID { get; set; } // PK/FK relationship.
  ...
}
```

See also:

[C# “does not contain a constructor that takes '1' arguments”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620852/c-sharp-does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-1-arguments)

[Does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016475/does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-2-arguments)